# Why does python come with so many similar, but subtly different functionality for fulfilling certain elementary computing tasks?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Sorry for being naive but I don't quite understand why python comes with so many similar, but probably subtly different functionality for fulfilling many basic tasks?

For example, what is the difference between `scipy.linspace / numpy.linspace /slice` in python?
Say I want to use a slice for scipy.optimize.brute:

```
scipy.optimize.brute(lambda x:-x, (slice(-100,100,3),))
```

But replacing `slice(-100,100,3)` to `numpy.linspace(-100,100,3)` or `scipy.linspace`(-100,100,3) just won' t work.

As another example,  I do not see why we have three different types `math.sin`, `scipy.sin` and `numpy.sin` and so forth. There must be a reason so that python designers provide so many alternatives. Any clarification?

Comment: Python doesn't "come with" numpy and scipy at all.

Comment: If your asking why 2 different 3rd party libraries have somewhat similar functions you are going to have to ask the author of the library.

Comment: @BrenBarn Good point. I meant python in general

Comment: As far as I know, mostly everything that has the same name in scipy and numpy is actually delivered by numpy. scipy sits on top of numpy and for convenience, some of the numpy namespace is exposed to scipy.

Comment: Anyone can write libraries that do what they want.  As Christian says, many things that are provided in both numpy and scipy are really the same thing.

Comment: 1) `slice` and `linspace` are totally different things; 2) `scipy.sin` and `numpy.sin` are identical things (look at `id(np.sin)` and `id(sp.sin)`) and this is just done for convenience; 3) `math.sin` does not operate on numpy arrays since numpy is not part of Python.

Answer (score 2):

One point to make about your specific examples is that NumPy and SciPy support vectorization (you can pass a sequence to `numpy.sin()` and create a sequence of values, `sin(x)`. You can't do this with `math.sin()`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.linspace(0,np.pi,100)
>>> y = np.sin(x)
>>> y
array([  0.00000000e+00,   3.17279335e-02,   6.34239197e-02,
     9.50560433e-02,   1.26592454e-01,   1.58001396e-01,
     1.89251244e-01,   2.20310533e-01,   2.51147987e-01,
     ...
     1.22464680e-16])
```

Another point to make about SciPy / NumPy is:

```
>>> import scipy as sp
>>> np.sin is sp.sin
True
```

They're the same method! NumPy / SciPy also gives access to some `math` module methods in its own namespace:

```
>>> import math
>>> np.math.factorial is sp.math.factorial is math.factorial
True
```

But as for why there isn't just one common way to do these things, I think that's just the bazaar-like nature of open source software libraries: these packages have bubbled up as the most popular and widely-used ones for the purpose; there hasn't been any top-down, cathedral-like planning behind it all.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about the `ranges` input to `brute`:

```
scipy.optimize.brute(lambda x:-x, (slice(-100,100,3),))
```

From its documentation:

> ranges : tuple
>    Each component of the ranges tuple must be either a “slice object” or a range tuple of the form (low, high). The program uses these to create the grid of points on which the objective function will be computed.

`numpy.linspace(-100,100,3)` (`scipy.linspace(-100,100,3)` is the same thing). is neither a slice or range tuple.  It is, more or less, an expansion of a slice.  But `brute` chooses to do its own thing with the slices.  Specifically after a certain tweaking it passes it to `mgrid`.

Nothing magical here.  It's just how the person(s) who wrote `scipy.optimize` chose to process its inputs.

A `python` `slice` is a simple object, one with `start`, `stop`, `step` attributes, and little else.  Indexing notation like `start:stop:step` get translated into slices.  But it the responsibility of objects like `lists` and `ndarray` to use those 3 values. While the inputs to `np.arange` are slice-like, the inputs to `linspace` are not.  The 3rd number is the number steps, not the step size.  `linspace` has a more refined handling of the endpoints.  In some cases the results are similar, in others the details matter.